# Multilanguage site by virtual subfolder (Apache)

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, multilingual, virtualhost, subdirectory

I want to have an architecture like that on a multilingual site :

> www.mydomain.tld/en/mypage
>   www.mydomain.tld/fr/mypage

I have multiple Rewrite rule like that :

> RewriteRule ^mypage$ mypage.php [L]
>   RewriteRule ^mypage2$ mypage2.php [L]

How to do a "prefix rule" that transform /en/* or /fr/* in RewriteRule ^*$ *.php?language=en|fr [L] ?

I've tried to work with differents combinations but without success :

> RewriteRule !^(fr|en)/ /fr%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
>   RewriteRule ^(fr|en)/ %{REQUEST_URI}?language=$1 [L,R=301]

An idea how to do that ?

-- Sorry for my English I'm French.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Or I edit all my rewrite rules like that RewriteRule ^(fr|en)/mypage$ mypage.php?language=$1 [L] but it's crappy.

Comment: No one can help me ? :(